# SQLite cursor in Python with statement

Tags: python, sqlite, database-cursor

I have the following code:

```
def executeOne(self, query, parameters):
    with self.connection as cursor:         
        cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        return cursor.fetchone()
```

When I call this method, it throws me the following error: `AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does self.connection have? a connection object? or maybe you are forgetting to call the function self.connection.cursor()....

Comment: Yes, `self.connection` has a connection object (`self.connection = sqlite3.connection('file.db')`). Where should I call the `cursor()` method? Doesn't the sqlite module associate the connection from the `with` statement with a cursor?

Comment: It does, but the cursor object is a separate instance, and you need to create that manually to access `cur.execute` `using cur = self.connection.cursor()`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason you are receiving the error is because the connection class does not have a method called `fetchone`. You need add `.cursor()` to create an instance of cursor and then wrap  it with [closing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) for it to work in a [with](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement.

```
from contextlib import closing
with closing(self.connectio.cursor()) as cur:
```

The easiest way to deal with this is to remove the `with` statement and manually close the `cursor`.

```
cur = self.connection.cursor() 
try:
    cur.execute(query, parameters) 
    return cur.fetchone()
finally:
    cur.close()
```

Comment: OK, I've solved it by creating a separate instance of the Cursor object inside the with statement. Thanks for pointing that out